# Stochastically dominated Poisson Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, point-processes

How can I prove, that a Poisson Point Process $\mathcal{P}_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ of the region $B_{r_n}(x)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ with intensity $nf$ is stochastically dominated by a Poisson random variable with mean $ r_*f^* $. $f^*$ is the supremum of the probability density and $r_*= \sup_{n\geq 1} \omega_d nr_n^d < \infty $, where $\omega_d$ is the volume of a $d$-dimensional unit ball.

In short:

$$\mathcal{P}_n(B_{r_n}(x)) \leq \operatorname{Poi}(r_*f^*).$$

I know that for Stochastic Dominance I have to compare the Cumulative distribution functions. My first question would be: What is the CDF of the given point process?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing that by $B_{r_n}(x)$ you mean the ball of radius $r_n>0$ centered at $x\in\mathbb R^d.$ If $r_n,\,\,n=1,2,3,\ldots$ supposed to be just any sequence of positive numbers? I'm also guessing that the c.d.f.s involved would be those of every one of the Poisson-distributed random variables involved, i.e. for every Borel subset of the ball, the number of random sites located within it is the random variable corresponding to that Borel set.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! The CDF of a Poisson-distributed variable is given by $F_{\lambda}(n) = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$. How does this relate to the numer of random sites in a Borel set?

Comment: The parameter $\lambda$ would be the measure of the Borel set, which would be the integral of the intensity function over that set. There is a separate Poisson-distributed random variable for each Borel set. For two such sets, the two Poisson-distributed random variables are independent if the measure of their intersection is $0$ (and again, "measure" means the integral of the intensity function over that set---in this case the integral over the intersection).